# Export lines or graphics without losing the details / generate graphics without having lines overlapping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, line, schematics

I am new to ArcGIS.

How do I easily reproduce a spatial diagram such the one attached (Picture); from shapefiles on ArcGIS.

[image: Typical Network]

I very often have to reproduce networks on Powerpoint at different scale without loosing details such as number of lines from A to B.
Exporting images directly from ArcGIS at certain scales makes those details difficult to notice, as lines close to each other tend to look like one.

**Is there a way to export lines or graphics without losing the details, or is there a way to at least generate graphics without having lines overlapping?**

(Note that in reality there only is about 30meters between the parallel lines, and that the distance between the red dot and the green square is 20km - I need to keep the relative location of point and the relative route of the lines, but at the same time represent all the lines although on the ground they are very close to one another )